# Can a RecyclerView cell consume RecyclerViews touch events?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-recyclerview, android-gesture

I have a RecyclerView where all cells are a custom view. In my custom view I have something which looks like a button. And when the user makes a long press on this button he/she can make a swipe gesture.

But when the user swipes the RecyclerView scrolls up and down.

Can my custom view consume this swipe gesture before the RecyclerView beginn to scroll?

In my custom view I implemented a [`GestureDetector`](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/making-interactive.html#inputgesture). It works so far for click and long press. I also overwrote [`boolean onScroll (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html#onScroll(android.view.MotionEvent,%20android.view.MotionEvent,%20float,%20float)) and return `true` to indicate the the scroll event is consumed but the RecyclerView scrolls anyway.

EDIT:

Here my code (snippet):

```
class EventListView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs),
    GestureDetector.  OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

    private val gestureDetector: GestureDetector


    init {

        gestureDetector = GestureDetector(context, this)
    }


    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        var result = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        if (!result) {
            if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
                Timber.i("ACTION_UP")

                animateAlpha(alpha, 0)
                result = true;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }


    //
    // OnGestureListener
    //

    override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return isInside(e)
    }

    override fun onShowPress(e: MotionEvent) {
        if (isInside(e))
            showPressState()
    }

    override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent) {

    }

    override fun onScroll(e1: MotionEvent, e2: MotionEvent, distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent, e2: MotionEvent, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    //
    // OnDoubleTapListener
    //

    override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onDoubleTapEvent(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to show your code so people can see for themselves if you're doing anything that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I added a code snippet, it is writen in Kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it. When I call `getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` in my custom view the RecyclerView stops scrolling